# iOS Chart errors due to no documentation

Tags: ios, swift, ios-charts

I want to include [Charts](https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts/blob/master/README.md) on a section of my side project. I struggle to get their [demo](https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts/blob/master/ChartsDemo/Classes/Demos/LineChart2ViewController.m) working. I do not know Objective C so I've [converted](https://objectivec2swift.com/#/home/converter/) their code to Swift. Im using Swift 3:

**viewDidLoad():**

```
self.title = "Filled Line Chart"
    self.chartView.delegate = self // after build: Thread 1:EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x……)
    self.chartView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    self.chartView.gridBackgroundColor = UIColor(red: CGFloat(51 / 255.0), green: CGFloat(181 / 255.0), blue: CGFloat(229 / 255.0), alpha: CGFloat(150 / 255.0))
    self.chartView.drawGridBackgroundEnabled = true
    self.chartView.drawBordersEnabled = true
    self.chartView.chartDescription.isEnabled = false
    self.chartView.pinchZoomEnabled = false
    self.chartView.dragEnabled = true
    chartView.scaleEnabled = true
    var l = chartView.legend
    l.isEnabled = false
    var xAxis = chartView.xAxis
    xAxis.isEnabled = false
    var leftAxis = chartView.leftAxis
    leftAxis.axisMaximum = 900.0
    leftAxis.axisMinimum = -250.0
    leftAxis.drawAxisLineEnabled = false
```

Since I dont know what to do from there, I dragged a line from my view to the code to create an `IBOutlet`: `@IBOutlet var chartView: BarChartView!`

In all it looks like this:

```
import UIKit
import Charts

class DashboardVC: UIViewController, ChartViewDelegate {

  @IBOutlet var chartView: BarChartView!

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

self.title = "Filled Line Chart"
        self.chartView.delegate = self
        self.chartView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        self.chartView.gridBackgroundColor = UIColor(red: CGFloat(51 / 255.0), green: CGFloat(181 / 255.0), blue: CGFloat(229 / 255.0), alpha: CGFloat(150 / 255.0))
        self.chartView.drawGridBackgroundEnabled = true
        self.chartView.drawBordersEnabled = true
        self.chartView.chartDescription?.isEnabled = false
        self.chartView.pinchZoomEnabled = false
        self.chartView.dragEnabled = true
        self.chartView.scaleXEnabled = true
        var l = chartView.legend
        l.isEnabled = false
        var xAxis = chartView.xAxis
        xAxis.isEnabled = false
        var leftAxis = chartView.leftAxis
        leftAxis.axisMaximum = 900.0
        leftAxis.axisMinimum = -250.0
        leftAxis.drawAxisLineEnabled = false
  }
}
```

Error I got with above:

[image]

The aim was to add a chart in a small container on my view but just to see of this moule works, I select the entire view to create the outlet. I see not documentation. I've looked on youtube for videos, searched for tutorials for this module but nothing. Spent 2hrs looking and so far no good. Would appreciate any little input.

Thanks.

EDIT:

As per comments/answer, Ive changed `isEnabled` to `enable`. Only one error, `Thread 1:EXC_BAD_ACCESS`. The fix brought me to [this](https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts/issues/110).

This simple question gets longer as when I made the change but selecting `Charts` for Module, I get the above error which points to my custom segue:

```
func goTodashboard() {

        let storyboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

        let dc: DashboardVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "dashboardVC") as! DashboardVC

        self.present(dc, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }
```

Basically, that code is called in `viewDidAppear()` from loginViewController. When user logs in, it goes to the dashboard. Is that the correct way to switch view? It works ok but the Charts having an issue with it.

Comment: you can find the official documentation at https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki  to resolve your errors simply use enabled instead of isEnabled

Comment: I have, thanks. Got a slightly different issue. See edit.

Comment: i suggest you take a closer look at segues and the prepare-method, that may resolve the bad access. Did you set the correct class to your uiview(barChart) in the storyboard?

Comment: @Tobi Thats where Im lost. I only have `LoginVC` and `DashboardVC`.

Comment: i would, without knowing more of your structure, call performSegue(withIdentifier: "Your Identifier", sender: /*login-button*/) after the login is proven correct and put all the other stuff in the prepare-method or wire up everything in the storyboard and disable the segue if login data are incorrect

Comment: if you struggle with setting up a class to the view open the storyboard > select the view that will display the chart > in the identity inspector (on the upper right corner, 3rd tab from left) > enter 'BarChartView' in the Class property and 'Charts' in the Module property

Comment: @Tobi Just about to say that. Ok, did that, no errors. View shows "No chart data available". The objectivec converter not converting the options for charts. Is that what's missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To narrow down the solution from my comments 
you can find the official documentation for the Charts framework [here](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki)

the `isEnabled`-Methods are getter, the corresponding setter method is `enabled`

instead of using a custom segue-function try to use the build-in `prepare`-method, you can call it programmatically with `performSegue(withIdentifier: "Your Identifier", sender: /*login-button*/)` after you validated the login as correct

make sure you set the right class to the `UIView` that displays your chart (in storyboard select the view and go to the identity inspector > enter 'BarChartView' in the Class property and 'Charts' in the Module property)

after everything works, you need to provide data to your chart:

let me give you an example

```
let data = Utils().getData()               
var dataEntries: [ChartDataEntry] = []

for i in 0..<data.count
{
  let dataEntry = ChartDataEntry(x:Double(data[i].xValue), y:Double(data[i].yValue))
  dataEntries.append(dataEntry)
}

let chartDataSet = BarChartDataSet(values: dataEntries, label: "Label")  
let chartData = BarChartData(dataSets: [chartDataSet])            
self.barChart.data = chartData
```

everything should be set up and working now

Comment: Ok I'll try this out later. Thanks

Comment: What is `Utils()`?

Comment: An example Classobject, from where you get your chart data belongs to you .. you could also hardcode them, read them from a database or receive them from a server ... it's up to you

Comment: Ok this worked but...not really "usable" as when I change graph types I get errors. However, what you've given works with `LineChart` and I'll accept. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

As I have observed that you need to hide description & legends so you are changing wrong property of **Charts framework** use below property for `enable / disable` description.

```
self.chartView.chartDescription?.enabled = false

let l  = chartView.legend as Legend
l.enabled = false

let xAxis = chartView.xAxis
xAxis.enabled = false
```

`isEnable` is a **readonly property** to check that feature is enable or not and its returning `YES/NO`.

Hope this will helps you.

Answer (score 0):

isEnable is Getting funcation ,can not be use for Setting. please use

xAxis.enable =  false